# mysql PREPARE statement

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I have a series of 16 PREPARE, EXECUTE and DEALLOCATE statements (in a stored procedure), each inserting rows into a diffterent table (table 1 to table16). eg:

```
SET @Command1 = CONCAT("insert into TABLE1" ,  ...etc.. );
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @Command1 ;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

SET @Command1 = CONCAT("insert into TABLE2" ,  ...etc.. );
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @Command1 ;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

.
.
.

SET @Command1 = CONCAT("insert into TABLE16" ,  ...etc.. );
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @Command1 ;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

When I execute the stored procedure, the INSERT works intermittently. Sometimes all the 16 inserts works, but sometimes they don't.

In the last CALL of the stored procedure, the first 2 inserts (into TABLE1 and TABLE2 ) and the last 4 inserts (TABLE 13 to 16) work, but not the inserts into Table 3 to 12.

Can you explain why? Can't be because I'm using the same variable/handle command1 and stmt1?

Comment: That's not enough [information](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). Post the generated statements (you can record them by inserting them into another table) and see if they generated any warnings or errors when the stored procedure was called. Also, why are you using `CONCAT` rather than parameters (`EXECUTE ... USING ...`)?

Comment: Within a stored procedure you can simply print the statements using SELECT, like `SELECT @Command1`; no need to `INSERT INTO` other table. Btw inserting into another table to debug why inserting into a table does not work might be difficult ;)

Comment: Is there actually any gain to CONCATing a string and than converting it to a prepared statement? It circumvents parameter binding and you're not using it more than once ...

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, the combinations of `Prepare` and `Execute` commands should be used with **placeholders** - saving you time with concat strings (maybe one of your concats simply goes wrong) and of course - prevent sql injections (yey!)

So... just build your statements like this one:

```
-- in MySQL ? is a placeholder
set @sampleQuery = 'select name into @testValue from myTable where id = ?'; 
set @idParam = 'NT54X9';

prepare sampleStatement from @sampleQuery;
execute sampleStatement using @idParam; -- `using` is the key point here
deallocate prepare sampleStatement;

select @testValue
```